# Where Clause for PgAdmin PostGIS

Tags: postgis, where-clause

I'm trying to select streams that are a certain distance away from cities. I have been able to do it for a few, but I would like to do it to the entire column that contains the cities name without having to do each individual city.

This is what I have so far

```
CREATE TABLE public.streams_cities AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.gid) b.gid, b.name, b.geom, s.city_name
    FROM public.cities_coutnies s
        LEFT JOIN public.streams b on ST_DWithin(s.geom, b.geom, 10560)
    WHERE s.city_name = 'ARVADA'
    OR s.city_name = 'BRIGHTON'
    OR s.city_name = 'COMMERCE CITY'
    OR s.city_name = 'DENVER'
    OR s.city_name = 'EDGEWATER'
    OR s.city_name = 'FEDERAL HEIGHT';
```

There must be a less time consuming way.

Comment: Are you trying to keep only those cities which have as a name `Arvada`, `Denver` etc? Then you could use `s.city_name in ('ARVADA', 'BRIGHTON', etc)`. If you would like to select based on all cities in another column you could do `WHERE s.city_name in (SELECT city_name FROM tableX)`.

Comment: Well, get rid of the WHERE clause if want to have all the cities processed :)